# inconsistent geom_polygon behavior (Windows vs. OS X)

Tags: r, ggplot2

It looks like `ggplot2::geom_polygon` acts differently running Windows vs. OSX. Here's an example:

```
library("ggplot2")
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), 
                     y = c(2,2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2), 
                     hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
ggplot(data=df) + geom_polygon(mapping=aes(x, y), fill="green")
```

Here's what this produces for me on Windows:

[image: windows]

...and on my Mac:

[image: mac]

It's maybe a bit confusing what behavior should be expected in the above example! Tracing the hole in the negative direction is more sensible, and gets consistent behavior (both like the Windows output above):

```
index <- 1:nrow(df)
index[df$hole] <- rev(index[df$hole])
dfReversed <- df[index,]
ggplot(data=dfReversed) + geom_polygon(mapping=aes(x, y), fill="green")
```

I'm using the same version of R and Ggplot2 for both:

Windows 8
OS X 10.9.1
R v3.0.2
Ggplot2 v0.9.3.1.

What causes this difference? Or more generally, how does `geom_polyon` decide what to draw in such confusing examples?

Comment: Direction matters with paths and holes, but I don't know if having the outer path running counterclockwise too is defined. If it isn't defined, then inconsistencies may happen.